# How to Carousel Layout with ViewPager2 in landscape

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I managed to make Carousel Layout using ViewPager2 in Android appication. but when I turn the app to landscape mode the bigger image in focus stretches and looks strange. How can I create a carousel layout in landscape using viewpager2. 
This is how I implemented for the portrait mode.

```
view_pager2.post {
      val pageMarginPx = containerView.context.resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.card_margin)
      val offsetPx = containerView.context.resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.card_offset)

      view_pager2.setPageTransformer { page, position ->
        val offset = position * -(2 * offsetPx + pageMarginPx)

        when {
          position < -1 -> page.translationX = -offset
          position <= 1 -> {
            val scaleFactor = max(PAGE_SCALE_FACTOR, 1 - abs(position - 0.14f))
            page.translationX = offset
            page.scaleY = scaleFactor
          }
          else -> {
            page.translationX = offset
          }
        }
      }

      view_pager2.currentItem = selectedCardIndex
      pageChangedListener.onPageSelected(view_pager2.currentItem)
    }
```